# Getting a NullPointerException while parsing JSON

Tags: java, android, json

Everything looks correct to me: Get results object, get series array, get object at index, and get data array.

```
private void downloadAllData() throws JSONException {

    queryApi();

    JSONObject results = mJsonResponse.getJSONObject("Results"); // NullPointerException here
    JSONArray seriesArray = results.getJSONArray("series");

    JSONObject DataSeries1 = seriesArray.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray DataArray1 = DataSeries.getJSONArray("data");

    JSONObject DataSeries2 = seriesArray.getJSONObject(1);
    JSONArray DataArray2 = DataSeries.getJSONArray("data");
```

JSON feed:

```
{"status":"REQUEST_SUCCEEDED","responseTime":36,"message":[],"Results":{
"series":
[{"seriesID":"431432","data":[{"year":"1977","period":"M12","periodName":"December","value":"160.7","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M11","periodName":"November","value":"161.3","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M10","periodName":"October","value":"162.2","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M09","periodName":"September","value":"162.5","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M08","periodName":"August","value":"163.4","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M07","periodName":"July","value":"164.0","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M06","periodName":"June","value":"164.6","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M05","periodName":"May","value":"165.8","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M04","periodName":"April","value":"166.7","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M03","periodName":"March","value":"167.9","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M02","periodName":"February","value":"169.1","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M01","periodName":"January","value":"170.6","footnotes":[{}]}]},
{"seriesID":"321432","data":[{"year":"1977","period":"M12","periodName":"December","value":"50.5","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M11","periodName":"November","value":"50.4","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M10","periodName":"October","value":"50.5","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M09","periodName":"September","value":"50.6","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M08","periodName":"August","value":"50.6","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M07","periodName":"July","value":"50.6","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M06","periodName":"June","value":"50.5","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M05","periodName":"May","value":"50.1","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M04","periodName":"April","value":"49.4","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M03","periodName":"March","value":"48.8","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M02","periodName":"February","value":"48.3","footnotes":[{}]},{"year":"1977","period":"M01","periodName":"January","value":"47.6","footnotes":[{}]}]}]
}}
```

Logcat:

```
04-10 22:16:59.519  10910-10937/com.learn.kent.mojito E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[DownloadService]
    Process: com.learn.kent.mojito, PID: 10910
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.learn.kent.mojito.service.DownloadService.downloadAllData(DownloadService.java:151)
            at com.learn.kent.mojito.service.DownloadService.onHandleIntent(DownloadService.java:83)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

04-10 22:16:59.659  10910-10910/com.learn.kent.mojito D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ 
Enabling debug mode 0
04-10 22:16:59.729  10910-10910/com.learn.kent.mojito I/ActivityManager﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42db38a8 time:59558459
04-10 22:17:00.369  10910-10910/com.learn.kent.mojito D/DownloadService﹕ {"Results":{"series":[{"data":[{"value":"50.5","year":"1977","period":"M12","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"December"},{"value":"50.4","year":"1977","period":"M11","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"November"},{"value":"50.5","year":"1977","period":"M10","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"October"},{"value":"50.6","year":"1977","period":"M09","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"September"},{"value":"50.6","year":"1977","period":"M08","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"August"},{"value":"50.6","year":"1977","period":"M07","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"July"},{"value":"50.5","year":"1977","period":"M06","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"June"},{"value":"50.1","year":"1977","period":"M05","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"May"},{"value":"49.4","year":"1977","period":"M04","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"April"},{"value":"48.8","year":"1977","period":"M03","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"March"},{"value":"48.3","year":"1977","period":"M02","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"February"},{"value":"47.6","year":"1977","period":"M01","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"January"}],"seriesID":"21432"},{"data":[{"value":"62.1","year":"1977","period":"M12","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"December"},{"value":"61.9","year":"1977","period":"M11","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"November"},{"value":"61.6","year":"1977","period":"M10","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"October"},{"value":"61.4","year":"1977","period":"M09","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"September"},{"value":"61.2","year":"1977","period":"M08","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"August"},{"value":"61.0","year":"1977","period":"M07","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"July"},{"value":"60.7","year":"1977","period":"M06","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"June"},{"value":"60.3","year":"1977","period":"M05","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"May"},{"value":"60.0","year":"1977","period":"M04","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"April"},{"value":"59.5","year":"1977","period":"M03","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"March"},{"value":"59.1","year":"1977","period":"M02","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"February"},{"value":"58.5","year":"1977","period":"M01","footnotes":[{}],"periodName":"January"}],"seriesID":"431432"}]},"message":[],"status":"REQUEST_SUCCEEDED","responseTime":44}
04-10 22:17:01.489  10910-10937/com.learn.kent.mojito I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 10910 SIG: 9
```

The JSON response in the logcat represents log.d(TAG, mJsonResponse.tostring)

Initializing mJsonResponse using Volley:

```
private void queryApi() throws JSONException {
        try {
            jsonObjectQuery.put("seriesid", seriesid);
            jsonObjectQuery.put("startyear", "" + startYear);
            jsonObjectQuery.put("endyear", "" + endYear);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                jsonObjectQuery, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                mJsonResponse = response; <--------------------------------
                Log.d(TAG, mJsonResponse.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                return headers;
            }
        };
        queue.add(jsonObjRequest);
    }
```

Comment: post your logcat. try to put them in `try-catch` block

Comment: Which line does line 151 of your `DownloadService.java` source code point to?

Comment: Have you initiated `mJsonResponse`?

Comment: Can't you debug it?  `mJsonResponse `is `null`.

Comment: Expanded the logcat. mJsonResponse isn't null on my log.d

Comment: try-catch block didn't work for me

Comment: what is line number 83?

Comment: can you show how did you create "mJsonResponse" object?

Comment: @Pwnies use GSON, and let it work for you :)

Comment: Panjak, I'm super new. I don't know how to use GSON, and I want to know how to use android's native JSON parser; this app is killing me though :.(

Comment: Added how I initialized mJsonResponse

Comment: @Pwnies your code seems perfect. Post the code where you're setting `mJsonResponse`. Further refer to this link for better understanding.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Is `mJsonResponse` a global variable? all this is in one class?

Comment: Yep, all one class; an intent service. mJsonResponse isn't global: private static JSONObject mJsonResponse;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `async task` that causes this error. You have to ensure that `mJsonResponse = response;` is called before `JSONObject results = mJsonResponse.getJSONObject("Results");`. 
Like:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    mJsonResponse = response; <--------------------------------
    Log.d(TAG, mJsonResponse.toString());
    JSONObject results = mJsonResponse.getJSONObject("Results"); // NullPointerException here
    JSONArray seriesArray = results.getJSONArray("series");

    JSONObject DataSeries1 = seriesArray.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray DataArray1 = DataSeries.getJSONArray("data");

    JSONObject DataSeries2 = seriesArray.getJSONObject(1);
    JSONArray DataArray2 = DataSeries.getJSONArray("data");
}
```

Comment: @Pwnies Yeah this could be a case.

Comment: Boom. problem solved, thanks SilentKnight. The only thing I had to add to your answer was a try-catch block.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
private JSONObject queryApi() {
    //your code  
    return mJsonResponse;
}

mJsonResponse = queryApi();
```

Comment: This took away my tunnel vision a bit, so it definitely deserved an upvote in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject DataSeries1 = seriesArray.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray DataArray1 = DataSeries1.getJSONArray("data");

JSONObject DataSeries2 = seriesArray.getJSONObject(1);
JSONArray DataArray2 = DataSeries2.getJSONArray("data");
```

Try this its work for me

Comment: change DataSeries.getJSONArray("data"); to DataSeries1.getJSONArray("data");